# Getting user input and making a decision

Tags: python, validation, case

I start my python script asking the user what they want to do?

```
def askUser():
    choice = input("Do you want to: \n(1) Go to stack overflow \n(2) Import from phone \n(3) Import from camcorder \n(4) Import from camcorder?");
    print ("You entered: %s " % choice);
```

I would then like to:

1. Confirm the user has entered something valid - single digit from 1 - 4.
2. Jump to corresponding function based on import.  Something like a switch case statement.

Any tips on how to do this in a pythonic way?

Comment: Is this for Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, semi-colons are not needed in python :) (yay).

Use a dictionary. Also, to get an input that will almost certainly be between 1-4, use a `while` loop to keep on asking for input until 1-4 is given:

```
def askUser():
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("Do you want to: \n(1) Go to stack overflow \n(2) Import from phone \n(3) Import from camcorder \n(4) Import from camcorder?"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input a number")
            continue
        if 0 < choice < 5:
            break
        else:
            print("That is not between 1 and 4! Try again:")
    print ("You entered: {} ".format(choice)) # Good to use format instead of string formatting with %
    mydict = {1:go_to_stackoverflow, 2:import_from_phone, 3:import_from_camcorder, 4:import_from_camcorder}
    mydict[choice]()
```

We use the `try/except` statements here to show if the input was not a number. If it wasn't, we use `continue` to start the while-loop from the beginning.

`.get()` gets the value from `mydict` with the input you give. As it returns a function, we put `()` afterwards to call the function.

Comment: You are not validating anything. What if the user enters "bollocks!" instead?

Comment: And the pythonic way to implement a switch is usually by using a dictionary dispatcher.

Comment: No, you moved it elsewhere, but you are not handling any exceptions that it'll throw.

Comment: *Now* we are getting somewhere. :-)

Comment: You don't need to use `.get()`; you just validated that the choice is between 1 and 4, so the key **will** be there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there any difference to mydict[n]() and mydict.get(n)()?

Comment: Yes, `mydict[n]` is one opcode, throws `KeyError` when no key is found; `mydict.get()` is two opcodes (look up the attribute `get`, call it as a function) and returns `None` when the key is not found. Incidentally, `None` cannot be called as a function, so that'd be a confusing error, I'd prefer a `KeyError` there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I knew about the errors and all, but I'll change it anyway, since you are right that the key will be there anyway